# How can I get my solider to get the Shaken status?

Tags: xcom-2

I want to max out Psi Operative's will , to that I need to get my shaken status, but despite getting him gravely wounded in my last battle, he did not get shaken. Is there any way to make sure he gets shaken ? I'm tired of walking into enemy fire and firing rockets on my own men.

Comment: You need to have shaken status to max out his will?  I didn't know that - where did you read that?

Comment: @BlueRaja-DannyPflughoeft When a soldier recovers from shaken status they get a small (4-12) boost to their will stat, so unless there's a cap on will, getting then removing shaken status will provide a will stat higher than it would otherwise have been.

Comment: Well the max will is 100 + Bonus from focus PCS, he is at max level so he won't get any will from leveling up, and his will is currently 95, (it was 90 before but I managed to get him shaken once before). The problem is that [according to the wiki](http://xcom.wikia.com/wiki/Personal_Combat_Sims#Notes) I can't equip him with the Superior Focus because that will cap his "natural" will increase so he can't get to max potential.

Comment: @Paul as user180012 answered, once he's been shaken, he can't get shaken again.

Comment: @Fambida I'm not so sure about that I found some [reddit posts](https://www.reddit.com/r/Xcom/comments/475exe/soldier_shaken_twice/) that imply that you can get shaken again

Comment: Psi skills don't use will. There's basically no reason to bother doing this.

Answer (score 3):

Given that your soldier already has been shaken he can't be shaken again.

For reference look up the earlier question:
What's the best way to prevent my squad members from being shaken?

Comment: According to [this reddit conversation](https://www.reddit.com/r/Xcom/comments/475exe/soldier_shaken_twice/) you can be shaken multiple times.

Comment: Pretty sure a soldier can be shaken multiple times. Happened to my main grenadier yesterday, but I suppose that could've been a bug?